# React app hosted through nginx stops being responsive on mobile

Tags: reactjs, nginx, material-ui

I'm trying to host a react website based on create-react-app using material ui on a raspberry pi 4 using Nginx. Running the site through `npm start` and going to localhost:3000 works fine, however when I run the production build, on mobile (or through inspect element using responsive mode) everything is shrunk way down and is barely readable.
[Left is npm start, right is hosted](https://i.stack.imgur.com/77TRA.png)

I'm running nginx/1.14.2 and v14.6.0 of node js, along with using the @material-ui libraries for the site.

I've made sure I've got the `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">` line in index.html, and I've tried adding the line

```
theme = responsiveFontSizes(theme);
```

to my MUI theme.

The text is being displayed through typography elements, for example:

```
<Typography variant = "h5">
      Welcome to the site!
</Typography>
```

Here is the code for one of the pages that might be relevant:

```
export default class Showcase extends Page{ 

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        
        this.state.body = <div style = {{textAlign:'center'}}>
            <Typography variant = "h5">
                Project Showcase
            </Typography>
            <Typography variant = "body2">
                There isn't much here yet, but there will be. <br/>
                Check back for various showcases of random stuff i've made
            </Typography>
        </div>;
    }
}
```

One of the pages

```
export default class Page extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            appBar: <div><TopBar pageName = {this.props.pageName}/></div>,
            body: <div>dont render the parent</div>
        };
    } 

    render() {

        const appBar = this.state.appBar;
        const body = this.state.body;
        const elements = [
            {
                root: appBar,
            },
            {
                root: <div style = {{padding:10}}>{body}</div>,
            },
        ];

        return (
            <div>
                {
                    elements.map((element) => <div>{element.root}</div>)
                }
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

The page parent class

```
let theme = createMuiTheme({
  palette: {
    type: "dark",
    primary: {
      main: '#202020',
    },
    background: {
      default: '#121212'
    },
  },
});

theme = responsiveFontSizes(theme);
```

The theme setup (I haven't used styling anywhere else)

EDIT:
I solved it, my issue was I had dns forwarding on my dns provider, turning it off and properly configuring my A record solved it

Answer (score 0):

As per my edit, I solved it, my issue was I had dns forwarding on my dns provider, turning it off and properly configuring my A record solved it